# Simplified Fiat-Shamir example generates wrong output

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, fiat-shamir

I am trying to implement the Fiat-Shamir identification protocol, however the end results always fail to match. I am using algorithm's description from [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~jjk8346/paper.pdf).

Preparation:

1. Select 2 prime integers and their product:

   ```
   n = 19 * 23 = 437
   ```
2. Select `s` coprime to `n`:

   ```
   s = 242
   ```
3. Compute `v`:

   ```
   v = (s^2) % n = 6
   ```

Now the round:

1. Select random `r` between `1` and `n - 1`:

   ```
   r = 410
   ```
2. Calculate `x`:

   ```
   x = (r^2) % n = 292
   ```
3. Choose `e` either 0 or 1:

   ```
   e = 1
   ```
4. Calculate `y`:

   ```
   y = (r * s^e) % n = 21
   ```

Now if `y^2` equals `(x * v^e) % n` then it's accepted. However in my case

```
y^2 = 441
(x * v^e) % n = 4
```

Why don't these numbers match? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "`y^2` equals `(x * v^e) % n`" should be "$y^2\equiv x\cdot v^e\pmod n$", written here as `$y^2\equiv x\cdot v^e\pmod n$`, which does hold. That's because `441 - 4` is a multiple of `437`, or/and because `441 % 437 == 4`

Comment: @fgrieu You mean `x * (v^e % n)`? It equals `1752`.

Comment: No, he means checking whether $y^2 \equiv x \cdot v^e\ (\bmod\  n)$.  One way of writing that is checking whether $(y^2 \bmod n) = ((x v^e) \bmod n)$.  Remember, the squaring of $y$ occurs within the group, and hence is implicitly done modulo $n$.

Comment: Oh I see now, I mistook the triple bar for equal sign. Now I see it means [modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar) [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). How can I accept your answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is one of notation for [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), at the point of the question reading

> if `y^2` equals `(x * v^e) % n` then..

Likely the textbook is about

> if $y^2\equiv x\cdot v^e\pmod n$ then..

By definition of $a\equiv b\pmod n$, that holds if and only if $n$ divides $a-b$ (or equivalently: $|b-a|$ is a multiple of $n$). In the question, `437` divides `441-4`, thus $y^2\equiv x\cdot v^e\pmod n$ holds.

Sometime, $a\equiv b\pmod n$ is written as $a=b\pmod n$, but rigorously the later means that $a$ is the set of solutions to the former. $a\equiv b\mod n$ or $a=b\mod n$ are also used, but the later is best avoided, because it is dangerously close to $a=b\bmod n$, to be read as $a=(b\bmod n)$ and thus rigorously meaning $0\le a<n$ and $|b-a|$ is a multiple of $n$. However, only a strict [Vulcan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_%28Star_Trek%29) would assume $0\le y^2<n$ when seeing $y^2=b\bmod n$.

Note: On this site, $y^2\equiv x\cdot v^e\pmod n$ can be written as `$y^2\equiv x\cdot v^e\pmod n$`. A right-click on a rendered formula then *Show Math As TeX Commands* will reveal the T<sub>E</sub>X code used. I often use this [T<sub>E</sub>X cheat sheet](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/ReferenceCards/TeXRefCard.v1.5.pdf).